# Seperate Char & Int into different JTable columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, hashmap

I have a character, integer hashmap in which I want the characters displayed in one column of my JTable and my integers displayed in another. What would be the best way to achieve this and properly display it?

Comment: Easiest way is to use a `DefaultTableModel` and iterate through the map, adding rows with the key/value pairs (that is assuming you know how to iterate through a map. If not, you may want to search for _that_ first. Then search for how to add a row to a JTable/DefaultTableModel). [Hint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

Comment: Thank you, right now I have my map being iterated by a couple other loops so hopefully it won't be too much of a problem. Didn't realize JTables were so in depth...

Comment: Work on it, and if you get stuck, edit your post with your attempt. We can help you fish out any mistakes.

Comment: See also [*JTable: Editors and Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).